# How does recursion work in a Countdown function

Tags: javascript, recursion, countdown

I'm learning a bit of JavaScript, but I'm having hard time understanding the lesson on FreeCodeCamp about the recursion countdown ([link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-countdown)).

In the lesson, there this initial example. But I'm confused on how it operates:

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

I see the steps that this function performs (in order), as something like this:

- `n` (5 in the beginning) is greater than 1, so go to the `else` statement.
- in the `else` statement I'll have a constant (`countArray`) assigned  to  do `countup(n - 1)`, which
  is 4.
- the next operation js encounters is `countArray.push(n)`, so it will push 4 into an array.
- then it encounters `return countArray`, which is 4.
- the function continues with 3,2,1 till the base condition reaches `n==0`, and in that case the
  function ends returning me an empty array.

I know this is not how it works, I'm simply "describing" how my noob mind works looking at this recursive function.

I looked at the solution of the exercise and other people's explanations, but I cannot understand why the function does not work like I described, and also why after reaching `n==0`, it starts to fill up an array counting up from 1 to 5.

I would like to understand this.

Comment: *”constant [..] which is 4”, “return [..] which is 4”* — Wrong. In both cases it’s an *array*, not 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realise that every execution of `countup` will have its own `n` and `countArray` variables.

It may help to visualise it. Each execution context is visualised as a "box". The variables in the outer boxes will still be there, when a function call returns.

The outermost box is the execution context that is created by the initial call: `countup(5)`:

```
// n is 5 and does not change
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  // n is 4 and does not change                                                |
|  const countArray = countup(n - 1);                                           |
|  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|  |  // n is 3 and does not change                                          |  |
|  |  const countArray = countup(n - 1);                                     |  |
|  |  +-------------------------------------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  |  // n is 2 and does not change                                    |  |  |
|  |  |  const countArray = countup(n - 1);                               |  |  |
|  |  |  +-------------------------------------------------------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  // n is 1 and does not change                              |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  const countArray = countup(n - 1);                         |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  +-------------------------------------------------------+  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  // n is 0 and does not change                        |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  return []; // the if-block is executed because n < 1 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  +-------------------------------------------------------+  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  // countArray is []                                        |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  countArray.push(n); // n is still 1                        |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  return countArray; // returns [1]                          |  |  |  |
|  |  |  +-------------------------------------------------------------+  |  |  |
|  |  |  // countArray is [1]                                             |  |  |
|  |  |  countArray.push(n); // n is still 2                              |  |  |
|  |  |  return countArray; // returns [1, 2]                             |  |  |
|  |  +-------------------------------------------------------------------+  |  |
|  |  // countArray is [1, 2]                                                |  |
|  |  countArray.push(n); // n is still 3                                    |  |
|  |  return countArray; // returns [1, 2, 3]                                |  |
|  +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+  |
|  // countArray is [1, 2, 3]                                                   |
|  countArray.push(n); // n is still 4                                          |
|  return countArray; // returns [1, 2, 3, 4]                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// countArray is [1, 2, 3, 4]
countArray.push(n); // n is still 5
return countArray; // returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually very helpful! Just one question: the fact that once n=0 (and we get our empty array back) javascript start to "unwind" his positions, so goin this time n=1, n=2, etc.. is because it is a property of the recursion or javascript in general operates like this?

Comment: It looks like `n` changes, but actually there are 6 different versions of the variable `n` here: each function call has its own `n`. So it is not that `n` is changing back from 1 to 2. No, the `n` that is 1 stops existing because the function execution that had that variable, returns. The *calling* function will still have the `n` whose value is 2 (you can see that in the diagram in my answer), and when *that* function returns, also *that* `n` will stop existing. In the mean while the variables with the name `n` that are "higher up the call stack" are still there, with values `5`, `4` and `3`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot, this was very helpful! I guess I really need to practice a lot more with recursion this way to "master it".

Answer (score 1):

You can just add some logging to visualize what is happening:

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    console.log('n = %d, returning empty array', n);
    return [];
  } else {
    console.log('n = %d, calling countup(%d - 1)', n, n);
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    console.log('n = %d, countArray is %s', n, JSON.stringify(countArray))
    console.log('n = %d, pushing n onto array', n);
    countArray.push(n);
    console.log('n = %d, returning %s', n, JSON.stringify(countArray));
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what the array looks like inside of each function call if this helps:

```
Array: 1             N: 1 
Array: 1,2           N: 2
Array: 1,2,3         N: 3
Array: 1,2,3,4       N: 4
Array: 1,2,3,4,5     N: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a console log in here like this, you can visualize it better.

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    console.log(`countup(${n}) returns ${countArray}`);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

What happens is that as soon as you hit that first invocation of `countup`, execution moves there. So, invoke it with 5 and you see the first output statement is run with a 1, because several more times it basically called itself.

countup (5) calls countup (4) calls countup(3) calls countup (2) calls countup (1) --
countup (1) returns 1, back to the caller of 2 which returns 2, 1, back to the caller of 3 returns 3, 2, 1...and so on back up to 5.